# Forms Data Submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

html code

```html
<form><input name="mailselect" type="email" id="mailselect" class="form-control"   required autocomplete="off">
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
        <input id="confirm_password" onkeyup='check()' onChange="check()" name="confirm_password" type="password" required autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="btc_register" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="referral" value="" id="myrefnum">
    <button type="button" name="btnsub" id="BtnSignUp">Submit </button>
</form>
```

javascript function

```js
$(document).on('click', '#BtnSignUp', function() {
 var email = $('#mailselect').val();
  var pass = $('#confirm_password').val();
  var RefNum = $('#myrefnum').val();

  if (email != '' && pass != '') {
    $.ajax({
      url: "register-execute.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        email: email,
        pass: pass,
        RefNum: RefNum
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#message').html('<div class="alert-success">' + data + '</div>');
      }
    });

    setInterval(function() {
      $('#message').html('');
    }, 5000);
  } else {
    alert("All Fields are required");
  }
});
```

my button is not working for register execute page. even not it is returning any message coming from php end.i have also edited my mistake in email input tag.but still not working. thankyou in advance for your kind help.

Comment: what's the error/problem?

Comment: You don't have anything with the id `mailselect`.

Comment: Add "id=mailselect" to email input.

Comment: How is this a php question?

Comment: this is html and javascript code.

Comment: Add your PHP code to the question.

Comment: its too long unable to add it.but i have checked my server end it working well.

Comment: <form id="clearfrm"><input name="email" type="email" id="mailselect" class="form-control"   required autocomplete="off"><input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control"  required autocomplete="off"><button type="button" name="btnsub" id="Btnlogin">Sign In </button></form>............$(document).on('click', '#Btnlogin', function(){SOME CODE  }); MY problem is that the button is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have anything with the id `mailselect`. To fix that you must change the input like this (you should also add a `name` attribute):

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="mailselect"  id="mailselect" required autocomplete="off">
```

Because there is no value for `#mailselect` you never enter the if condition here:

```
if (email != '' && pass != '') {
```

### In addition -

I know you didn't post your PHP here but I can assume, based on your coding here a couple of things you should pay attention to:

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

**Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: can be closed as off-topic/can't be repro. then?

Comment: It's not exactly a typo @treyBake, but yes - it could be closed for that.

Comment: yeah not a typo fo' sho' - more on the can't be repro. side :)

Comment: plz help me out.i have spended 2 days but no solution. the reason i am sending data by javascript is that i want to display the msg coming from php end

Comment: Make the changes I have posted here, then test @ali

Comment: i had made it. but still not working

Comment: Are you getting ANY errors? Can you add your PHP to the question @ali?

Comment: on button type submit it validates the email.but on type button it does not. how to do that